# Laravel 4.1 blade linking to user profile picture

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, assets, laravel-blade

I am trying to link to a user profile image in Laravels blade template but I am only getting errors here.

This is my image tag containing the link:

```
<img class="img-circle dashboardprofileimage" src="{{ URL::asset('img/profile_pictures/users/{{ Auth::user()->profile_picture }}') }}"/>
```

I would be very happy if anyone could help me out here. I guess its a simple thing but I have tried quite a lot of times now.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is using nested {{ }}, you just need it once. Check out the correct code below:

```
<img 
class="img-circle dashboardprofileimage" 
src="{{ 
URL::asset('img/profile_pictures/users/' . Auth::user()->profile_picture) 
}}" />
```

Note: it's splited into several lines for better legibility.

Answer (score 1):

you just use `{{ }}` one time to print `URL::asset()` and `Auth::user()`

```
<img class="img-circle dashboardprofileimage" src="{{ URL::asset('img/profile_pictures/users/'.Auth::user()->profile_picture) }}"/>
```